# How to get radius of a Circle Shape after I scaled it [JavaFX]

Tags: javafx-8, shapes, geometry

I'm trying to get the radius of a Circle Shape after I scaled it. I don't know how to do it. I'm developing a software (with javaFX library) that will let the user add Shapes (Circle, Rectangle, Squares,...)to a Panel, simply "modify" them, save the drawing and load it. I'm managing the saving/loading stuff by cycling through the Nodes the user added (there's a button to create Circle, Rectangle, ... and add it to the Panel), taking the properties I need to load them (centerX, centerY, scaleX, scaleY, ...) and, when button "save" pressed, to save them in a txt file. (stil working on loading, but my thought was to read the previous txt file and cycle it to re-create Shapes on panel in the same position, scale, rotation.)

Here's the code I wrote this is the portion of code that create circle:

```
 public Circle createCircle(double x, double y, double r, Color color) { 

        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, r, color);
        circle.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

        circle.setOnMousePressed((t) -> {
          orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
          orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();

          Circle c = (Circle) (t.getSource());
          c.toFront();

        });
        circle.setOnMouseDragged((t) -> {
          double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
          double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;

          Circle c = (Circle) (t.getSource());

          c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + offsetX);
          c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + offsetY);

          orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
          orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
        });

        return circle;
      }
```

Here's the code i use to scale it:

```
public void addMouseScrolling(Node node) {
   node.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
       // Adjust the zoom factor as per your requirement
       double zoomFactor = 1.05;
       double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
       if (deltaY < 0){
           zoomFactor = 2.0 - zoomFactor;
       }
       node.setScaleX(node.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
       node.setScaleY(node.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
   });
```

}

And this is the code of the save button:

```
Button btn2 = new Button("Save");
  btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

             int i=0;
             for (Node node: root.getChildren()) i++;
             String stringa_salvataggio[] = new String[i];
             String stringa="";
             i=0;
             String scal_X_s, scal_Y_s, Lyt_X_s, Lyt_Y_s, width_s, height_s;
            for (Node node: root.getChildren()){
                String stringa_nodo = node.toString();  
                Double scal_X = node.getScaleX(); 
                scal_X_s = Double.toString(scal_X);
                Double scal_Y = node.getScaleY();
                scal_Y_s = Double.toString(scal_X);
                Double Lyt_X = node.getLayoutX(); 
                Lyt_X_s = Double.toString(scal_X);
                Double Lyt_Y = node.getLayoutY(); 
                Lyt_Y_s = Double.toString(scal_X);
                Double width = node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
                width_s = Double.toString(scal_X);
                Double height = node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight();
                height_s = Double.toString(scal_X);

                stringa = stringa + scal_X_s + scal_Y_s + "\n";
                stringa_salvataggio[i] = stringa; 
                System.out.println("-------");
                i++;
                System.out.println("Nodo " + i + ":");
                System.out.println("scalX:" + scal_X);
                System.out.println("scalY:" + scal_Y);
                System.out.println("LayoutX:" + Lyt_X);
                System.out.println("LayoutY:" + Lyt_Y);
                System.out.println("Width:" + width);
                System.out.println("Height:" + height);
                System.out.println(stringa_nodo);
                //save on .txt

            }
            System.out.println(stringa_salvataggio);
        }
});
```

As I said before, I don't know how to get the radius of Circle to recreate it on loading. Rectangles and squares aren't a problem, I can take all infos I need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking: you get the radius of a circle by calling `getRadius()` (obviously you need to downcast it to a circle first). Note that `getLayoutBounds().getWidth()` will not necessarily give you the same as `getWidth()` for a `Rectangle`, depending on the `stroke`, so you probably need to explicitly call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on `Rectangle`s.

Comment: I'm trying to get the radius of the Circles I draw, but it's always the same (I figured out how to downcast the node to a circle, ty) even if i enlarge it.
I'll try to explain better: I create a Circle, then I mousescroll it to enlarge/reduce the size, then (when I press the save buton) I do the getRadius() but it's always the same radius.

Comment: Yes, because you never change it (at least, not in any of the code that you have posted). As long as you restore both the radius and the scale, you get back the circle that was saved.

Comment: Why do I never change it? I have the _addMouseScrolling(Node node)_ method to setScaleX and setScaleY. (when I try to get these (getScaleX and getScaleY) they're always equal 0)

Comment: I see that. All that does is change the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties. It doesn't change the radius.

Comment: I'm feeling pretty stupid, but I don't get why it doesn't change. I'm applying a scale to the Circle, but with 'getScaleX/Y' it doesn't give me anything. When i mousescroll the Circle it actually get scaled bigger or smaller, but I can't get that scaling values.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong, i got the scaling values. Really really really thanks for the help!!!